# 8-pin IC chip memory

Tags: integrated-circuit

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with a medical laser. My client has a laser which shipped with some default values. 
At the moment when we query the values they are totally different from what we expect.
Two parameters are off. Value A should be 3000, it is 0 and Value B should be 0, it is 3000.
We think the problem is with a singular 8-Pin IC-chip present in the housing of a box that controls all the valves in the laser.

Laser type: Excimer laser used for spectacle correction - made by Lambda-Physik Germany.
Lambda Physik says they no longer manufacture the laser and so we're stuck with this and virtually no support.

I need to know whether it will be possible to reprogram this chip.

Comment: You seem like a nice guy so sorry to say that repair questions are off-topic for this site. I will say that just because they don't make it anymore doesn't mean they won't support you. Imagine a garage saying that to you because your old ford escort or your precious e type jag isn't being made any more. Dig deeper is my advice.

Comment: I'm pretty satisfied with the answer I got for this question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You're asking for trouble self repairing an out of service invasive medical device that burns people's corneas.  Your patients deserve better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum you should tell us the part number of the chip you suspect.. there are many hundreds (perhaps thousands) of possibilities.

That  said, serial EEPROM memories do eventually wear out. You could try removing the chip and replacing it with a new chip (they're very cheap, probably less than a dollar). It's possible that the chip will be detected as new and reprogrammed by the system processor to factory default values. The chip has to be programmed somehow and this is one way it can be done. If it doesn't work then put the old one back in and no harm done (assuming the person doing the replacement is competent).

If the memory in the chip has simply been corrupted and the chip is still working, then you will need to find someone who has a service manual or knowledge from such a document, and this is not the place to find it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could I have your email , I could send you a picture of the chip. Furthermore I am open to a professional consultation if you should consent.

Comment: The chip has three rows of characters on it, first row: CHN - M, second row: 93C46 6, third row: k03014

Comment: 93C46 is an eeprom manufactured by Microchip

Comment: It's very common part. Originally made by National I think, but  with many other sources. The data currently in it can be downloaded and analyzed- it may incorporate error correction encoding so may not be completely straightforward (or it might be). Feel free to contact me but that is not my main purpose for being here.

Comment: P.S. I first used this particular chip ca. 1990 (25 years ago!)- for temperature controller parameter storage. We later moved  to I2C and SPI chips- the 93C46 family uses a NS protocol. Hyundai (the same company who makes cars and cargo ships) made  a version of it!

Comment: Hey Sphero, thanks a lot for all your info, how do I contact you? do you have a twitter handle or github?

Comment: Linkedin will work (slowly) or speff at interlog dot c*m. I'm currently in China (Hangzhou, Hefei, Ningbo, Shenzhen) so patience..